# Silverlight 3 datagrid: How to add scrollwheel support?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

Datagrid in silverlight 3 toolkit is not responding to scrollwheel(mousewheel). Is there any way to get support of scroll wheel?

Comment: I have tried wrapping the datagrid in a scrollviewer. The mousewheel support has enabled but the headers of the datagrid are not fixed. :(. Seems like not a good idea.

Comment: Can we add mousewheel support using behaviors?

Answer (score 3):

Below is the behavior I am using. And below that is how you attach it to the datagrid in xaml.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Automation.Peers;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Automation.Provider;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace GLS.Gui.Helper.Behaviors
{
    public class MouseWheelScrollBehavior : Behavior<Control>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the peer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The peer.</value>
        private AutomationPeer Peer { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called after the behavior is attached to an AssociatedObject.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Override this to hook up functionality to the AssociatedObject.</remarks>
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            this.Peer = FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(this.AssociatedObject);

            if (this.Peer == null)
                this.Peer = FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.CreatePeerForElement(this.AssociatedObject);

            this.AssociatedObject.MouseWheel += new MouseWheelEventHandler(AssociatedObject_MouseWheel);
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the behavior is being detached from its AssociatedObject, but before it has actually occurred.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Override this to unhook functionality from the AssociatedObject.</remarks>
        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.MouseWheel -= new MouseWheelEventHandler(AssociatedObject_MouseWheel);
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the MouseWheel event of the AssociatedObject control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        void AssociatedObject_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do not handle already handled events
            if (e.Handled)
                return;

            this.AssociatedObject.Focus();

            int direction = Math.Sign(e.Delta);

            ScrollAmount scrollAmount =
                (direction < 0) ? ScrollAmount.SmallIncrement : ScrollAmount.SmallDecrement;

            if (this.Peer != null)
            {
                IScrollProvider scrollProvider =
                    this.Peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Scroll) as IScrollProvider;

                bool shiftKey = (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift;

                if (scrollProvider != null && scrollProvider.VerticallyScrollable && !shiftKey)
                {
                    scrollProvider.Scroll(ScrollAmount.NoAmount, scrollAmount);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else if (scrollProvider != null && scrollProvider.VerticallyScrollable && shiftKey)
                {
                    scrollProvider.Scroll(scrollAmount, ScrollAmount.NoAmount);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }


            }
        }
    }


}
```

How to attach the behavior:

```
<data:DataGrid>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <b:MouseWheelScrollBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </data:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Kudos to Andrea Boschin who wrote it:  
http://silverlightplayground.boschin.it/post/2009/07/10/Silverlight-30-RTW-An-universal-MouseWheelScrolling-behavior.aspx

Answer (score 0):

An other way to do this (very basic example):
xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <data:DataGrid x:Name="dg" Height="100">
        <ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility>true</ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility>
    </data:DataGrid>
```

CS:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    IList<Person> list = new List<Person>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list.Add(new Person("Pieter1","Nijs"));
        list.Add(new Person("Pieter2", "Nijs"));
        list.Add(new Person("Pieter3", "Nijs"));
        list.Add(new Person("Pieter4", "Nijs"));
        list.Add(new Person("Pieter5", "Nijs"));
        list.Add(new Person("Pieter6", "Nijs"));
        list.Add(new Person("Pieter7", "Nijs"));
        list.Add(new Person("Pieter8", "Nijs"));
        dg.ItemsSource = list;
        dg.MouseWheel += new MouseWheelEventHandler(dg_MouseWheel);
    }

    void dg_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            dg.ScrollIntoView(list[dg.SelectedIndex + 2], null);
        }
        else
        {
            dg.ScrollIntoView(list[dg.SelectedIndex - 2], null);
        }
    }
}
```

So, what I do here is quite simple!
I add an EventHandler to the `DataGrid MouseWheel` - event. In that handler I retreive the `e.Delta` (this is the amount the wheel has changed since the last time) so I know if the user scrolled up (positive Delta) or down (negative Delta). And then I call the `ScrollIntoView`-method of the DataGrid, where I can specify to what row the Grid should scroll to. 
As mentioned, this is a very basic example! This is just to show you how it could work! You should add extra logic to make sure you don't go out of bounce!

Comment: Any idea how to do 2 finger scrolling in silver light 4 for my data grid